# Are there any switcheable "states" possible in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to draw button in Illestrator and make it with several states (like normal, pressed, dimmed). Can I draw all this and them quickly switch between button states? Also I would like to export current active state to SVG etc.

Comment: Adobe XD has [button state functionality](https://xd.adobe.com/ideas/process/ui-design/designing-interactive-buttons-states/), if that's any help to you. Also, you can [export design assets](https://www.xdguru.com/adobe-xd-guide/exporting/) directly from XD as SVG.

Answer (score 1):

Unless something has been added very recently, **no**, this isn't possible in Illustrator.

The *best* you could *possibly* do would be a collection of Symbols, then you can *manually* replace one symbol for another - scale and transformations would remain in tact. But this is *far, far* from anything dynamic.

InDesign *does* offer "states" for buttons. But whether or not Indesign is even feasible to use would depend upon the project.